# Filter View Reference results in paragraph based on taxonomy term selected in Drupal's backend

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-9

I have a paragraph named "Car Slider" and a Content Typ "Cars".
The content type consists of different fields like name, make etc. as well as a "Tags" taxonomy reference.
The car slider paragraph consists of fields like headline, description, and a Views Reference to display cars in a slider.

Right now I have different view displays to display only cars with specific tags in the slider, but it sounds unnecessary to have tons of displays, instead I'd prefer to have a dropdown in the backend editor the praragraph where I select the relevant tags and the view filters results to only that tag.
I want to use this to display sliders consisting cars of different categories/tags.

I am aware of the Expose Filter option, but this exposes the filter to the frontend/end-user, but I want to expose it to the admin who decides which content slider to add to the page.

I couldn't find a way to achieve this so far. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: does this help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258003/more-filter-options-on-admin-content/258004

Comment: No, as this only applies to the Content overview page of the backend. I'm looking for a taxononmy dropdown in the management area of the Drupal backend for Views reference fields.